# jQuery Date Picker - changing the date relative to each other

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hello i am trying to create a booking form, where the users can only choose from 1 to 14 days (From the current date +1). The problem i've got is that the EndDate (here #til) is set to 14 days from todays date. So if i go forth a month on StartDate(here #fra) i cannot choose anything in the EndDate.

How do i make it so EndDate is set relatively to the StartDate?

```
$( function valgavdato() {
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",

    from = $( "#fra" )
      .datepicker({
        minDate: '0+',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
      }),
    to = $( "#til" ).datepicker({
      maxDate: '14+',
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1
    })
    .on( "change", function() {
      from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
    });

  function getDate( element ) {
    var date;
    try {
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
    } catch( error ) {
      date = null;
    }

    return date;
  }
} );
```

Comment: use select event to update other datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that `maxDate` is set on load as "today" +14.
You have to calculate 14 days + the picked date...

So, here is something working.
It *may not be the cleanest* way to code it...
But still... It works.

The only changes (additions) are in `#fra` on change.

```js
$( function valgavdato() {
    var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
        to_MaxDate = 14;    // From date + this = to maxDate

        from = $( "#fra" )
    .datepicker({
        minDate: '0+',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
    })
    .on( "change", function() {
        var PickedDate = getDate( this );
        // See that date is in UTC format.
        console.log( "From DatePicker: "+JSON.stringify(PickedDate) );
        
        // Process the picked date.
        var tempDay = PickedDate.getDate() + to_MaxDate; // Add a number of days to the picked date.
        var tempMonth = PickedDate.getMonth() + 1;   // Because months are zero based.
        var tempYear = PickedDate.getYear() + 1900; // Because years are 1900 based
        console.log( "Temp date: "+ tempYear+"/"+tempMonth+"/"+tempDay +" --- It may look impossible... But Date() handles it.");

        // Create a date object in a UTC format.
        var newMaxDate = new Date(Date.UTC(tempYear, tempMonth-1, tempDay, 23, 59, 59));
        console.log(  "New max date: : "+ JSON.stringify(newMaxDate) );

        // Set the minDate ans maxDate options.  
        to.datepicker( "option", {"minDate": PickedDate, "maxDate": newMaxDate});

    }),
        to = $( "#til" ).datepicker({
            maxDate: '14+',
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1
        })
    .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
    });

    function getDate( element ) {
        var date;
        try {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
        } catch( error ) {
            date = null;
        }

        return date;
    }
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<input type="text" id="fra"><br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="til">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But your answer gives me 16 days instead of 14.

Comment: Are you sure you counted correctly? What I see is the selected date (not counted) + 14 days (like it behaved by default without taking the picked date in account). If you want a total of 14 selectable dates only, just change `var newMaxDate = new Date(Date.UTC(tempYear, tempMonth-1, tempDay, 23, 59, 59));` for `var newMaxDate = new Date(Date.UTC(tempYear, tempMonth-1, tempDay, 0, 0, 0));`

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, it works perfectly now :)